# Creating a function to allocate a array of strings in C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm working on a minisql code in C and i having some issues to allocate array of strings. I made a function called "alocaString" to do this (bc i'm using that a lot), but i don't think is working.
When the code reaches the line "strncpy(lista[qtnPalavras], splitStr, 100);" in the function "listaPalavras" (that have the purpose of split a string in different types of characters) a file named "strcpy-avx2.S" is created, one of the arguments of that function (**lista) is allocated with "alocaString" so i think the problem is in that function.

I already try to use valgrind and shows "is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]" to all arrays of strings that i tried to use on that function, but i'm initializing them inside of the function

```
int alocaString (char **string, int tamanho, int posicoes){
    string = malloc (posicoes * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < posicoes; i++){
        string [i] = malloc (tamanho * sizeof(char));
        if (string[i] == NULL){return 0;}
    }
    return **string;
}

void desalocaString (char **string, int posicoes){
    for (int i = 0; i < (posicoes); i++){
        free (string[i]);
    }
    free (string);
}

int listaPalavras(char *entrada, char **lista, char *separador){ // lista as palavras
  char *splitStr;
  int qtnPalavras = 0;
  splitStr = strtok(entrada, separador);

  while (splitStr != NULL){
        strncpy(lista[qtnPalavras], splitStr, 100);
        qtnPalavras++;
        splitStr = strtok(NULL, separador);
    }
    return qtnPalavras;
}
```

Comment: and since you are overwriting the argument `char **string` it would be better as a local variable, not an argument.

Comment: @user3121023 i change to char **alocaString and right now i am having another issue. When i run the code it shows a "free(): invalid pointer" when is deallocating memory

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using these functions like this:

```
alocaString(lista, tamanho, posicoes);
listaPalavras(some_string, lista, some_delimiters);
desalocaString(arr);
```

Even without looking at the code, it seems logically wrong to allocate an array of strings first and then populate it if you do not already know how many strings it will need to fit. If you happen to allocate an array of `n` strings, but your `listaPalavras()` functions splits the provided string into `n+1` or more substrings, you're going to overflow your previously allocated array. Nonetheless, this can be done taking the appropriate precautions, like carrying around sizes and checking them to avoid overflow.

The only sane way to achieve what you want is therefore to either (A) count the number of delimiters in the string first to know in advantage how many pointers you will need or (B) dynamically allocate the needed amount in `listaPalavras()` while splitting. You seem to be going with something similar to option A, but your code is flawed.

The `desalocaString()` is the only function that seems correct.

A correct implementation of `alocaString()` would *return the allocated array* (or `NULL` in case of failure), but you are returning `**string` which is just the first character of the first string. Needless to say, this does not make much sense. You don't need to take a `char **` parameter, just the sizes. Secondly, in case of failure of *any* of the calls to `malloc()` you should free the previously allocated ones before returning `NULL`.

```
char **alocaString (unsigned tamanho, unsigned posicoes) {
    char **lista = malloc(posicoes * sizeof(char*));

    if (lista == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < posicoes; i++) {
        lista[i] = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char));

        if (lista[i] == NULL) {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(lista[j]);
            free(lista);

            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return lista;
}
```

As per `listaPalavras()`, which has the job of splitting the given string into other strings and copying them into the previously allocated array, to avoid overflowing the given array of strings you will need to also provide its length as well as the length of the previously allocated strings as argument (let's call them `posicoes` and `tamanho` like for the above function). Moreover, `strncpy()` will *not* add a NUL-terminator (`\0`) to the destination string if it is not found in the source string within the first `n` characters (`n` being the third argument), so you will need to add it yourself to make sure your strings are correctly terminated.

```
unsigned listaPalavras(const char *entrada, char *separador, char **lista, unsigned posicoes, unsigned tamanho) {
    char *splitStr;
    unsigned qtnPalavras = 0;

    splitStr = strtok(entrada, separador);

    while (qtnPalavras < posicoes && splitStr != NULL){
        strncpy(lista[qtnPalavras], splitStr, tamanho);
        lista[qtnPalavras][tamanho - 1] = '\0';
        qtnPalavras++;
        splitStr = strtok(NULL, separador);
    }

    return qtnPalavras;
}
```

Finally the code of the caller should look something like this:

```
char **lista;
unsigned tamanho = 100;
unsigned posicoes = 10;
unsigned palavras;

lista = alocaString(tamanho, posicoes);
if (lista == NULL) {
    // handle the error somehow
}

palavras = listaPalavras(YOUR_STRING, YOUR_DELIMITERS, lista, posicoes, tamanho);

desalocaString(lista);
```

This should work fine, however you are limited by the fact that:

1. You cannot know beforehand the number of substrings that `strtok()` will find.
2. You cannot know beforehand the length of any of those substrings.

Therefore, allocating the needed `lista` dynamically inside `listaPalavras()` would make more sense.

Finally, as a side note, the names of your functions are misleading: if you need to allocate an array of strings, you might want to choose a better name than `alocaString()` which seems to imply that you are allocating a *single* string. Maybe `alocaLista()` and `dealocaLista()` would be better choices.

Comment: @mebeim i tried that, but it's giving another issue, it creates a file named "strlen-avx2.S"

Comment: @BeatrizCardoso you will have to be a lot more specific than that. Update your question adding how you compile and execute the program and the output at any step.